# Use of MPI_Bcast in this example from Using MPI, Third Edition

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

I do not understand why **MPI_Bcast** is used in the worker part of the code? That has been done in the manager part already so each worker should have the vector **b**.

And if this were true and we are supposed to use **MPI_Bcast** in the worker part of the code, then a second problem arises. How does it know the vector **b** ? That has been defined in the manager part.

Sorry I am learning MPI, this may be a trivial question.

```
 program main
 use mpi
 integer MAX_ROWS, MAX_COLS, rows, cols
 parameter (MAX_ROWS = 1000, MAX_COLS = 1000)
 double precision a(MAX_ROWS,MAX_COLS), b(MAX_COLS)
 double precision c(MAX_ROWS), buffer(MAX_COLS), ans

 integer myid, manager, numprocs, ierr, status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)
 integer i, j, numsent, sender
 integer anstype, row

 call MPI_INIT(ierr)
 call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, myid, ierr)
 call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, numprocs, ierr)
 manager = 0
 rows   = 100
 cols   = 100

 if (myid .eq. manager) then
!     manager initializes and then dispatches
!     initialize a and b  (arbitrary)
    do j = 1,cols
       b(j) = 1
       do i = 1,rows
          a(i,j) = i
       enddo
    enddo
    numsent = 0
!     send b to each worker process
    call MPI_BCAST(b, cols, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, manager, &
                   MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
    !  send a row to each worker process; tag with row number
    do i = 1,min(numprocs-1,rows)
       do j = 1,cols
          buffer(j) = a(i,j)
       enddo
       call MPI_SEND(buffer, cols, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, i, &
                     i, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
       numsent = numsent+1
    enddo
    do i = 1,rows
       call MPI_RECV(ans, 1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, &
                     MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, &
                     MPI_COMM_WORLD, status, ierr)
       sender     = status(MPI_SOURCE)
       anstype    = status(MPI_TAG)       ! row is tag value
       c(anstype) = ans
       if (numsent .lt. rows) then        ! send another row
          do j = 1,cols
             buffer(j) = a(numsent+1,j)
          enddo
          call MPI_SEND(buffer, cols, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, &
                        sender, numsent+1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
          numsent = numsent+1
       else      ! Tell sender that there is no more work
          call MPI_SEND(MPI_BOTTOM, 0, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, &
               sender, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
       endif
    enddo
    !        print out the answer
    do i = 1,cols
       print *, "c(", i, ") = ", c(i)
    enddo
 else
    !     workers receive b, then compute dot products until
    !     done message received
    call MPI_BCAST(b, cols, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, manager, &
                   MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
    if (myid .le. rows) then
       ! skip if more processes than work
       do
          call MPI_RECV(buffer, cols, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, &
                        manager, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &
                        status, ierr)
          if (status(MPI_TAG) .eq. 0) exit
          row = status(MPI_TAG)
          ans = 0.0
          do i = 1,cols
             ans = ans+buffer(i)*b(i)
          enddo
          call MPI_SEND(ans, 1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, manager, &
                        row, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
       enddo
    endif
 endif

call MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)
end
```

Comment: If you read the semantic of `MPI_Bcast()` (or any MPI collective operation) you will understand why not only the manager has to invoke it.

Comment: `MPI_Bcast()` only works when called by both the source of information and by all the other ranks in the communicator.